# show $\alpha^{-1}$ is continuous if $\alpha \in C^r$ is bijective, and $D\alpha$ is nonsingular

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 196, it is given that

[image]

However, if $\alpha$ is of class $C^r$, one-to-one and onto, and $D\alpha$ is nonsingular for $x \in U$, isn' $\alpha^{-1}$ continuous by the inverse Function Theorem? If so, why does the author include requirement $(2)$? Is it for pedagogical purposes that for the case with boundary, we cannot use the Inverse Function Theorem?

Note that, for manifolds with boundary, the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be $\mathbb{H}^k$, too, and for this particular case, I have already seen a counterexample where $\alpha^{-1}$ is not continuous (see page 202 in the same book).

**Edit:**

I think I figured what I was missing; Can you check the logic that I have given in the comments of the given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,... it turned out that the inverse function theorem is valid only for map from $\mathbb{R}^n $ to $\mathbb{R}^n $, which is not the case in here, so we cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you read two pages down, i.e. page 198, there is an example, namely

$$\alpha: t \mapsto \sin2t(\vert \cos t \vert, \sin t)$$ defined from $(0,\pi)$ into $\mathbb R^2$ which explains why the hypothesis $\alpha^{-1}$ continuous is important. The Implicit Function Theorem doesn’t work as we’re working on manifolds not in full space. The example gives a clear highly on that: the image of the open subset $(0,\pi)$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I meant inverse function theorem, there was a typo in the body of the question.

Comment: Moreover, I have calculated the the derivative of $\alpha$ in that example, and for the values $t \in (\pi/2, \pi)$, there are points where $D\alpha$ take the zero value.

Comment: By the way, I'm realising that the inverse function theorem assumes that $D\alpha (x)$ is non-singular for $x$ in the domain; meaning that the resulting matrix of real  numbers has non-zero determinant for each point in the domain, whereas in the definition of a coordinate patch, it requires the rank of $D\alpha $ to be $k$, meaning the columns(or rows) of $D\alpha$ (having entries as a function $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$) are linearly independent each other; but this only means that the determinant of $D\alpha (x)$ is not zero **for all** $x$ in the domain. ...

Comment: Therefore, there still might some points where the determinant of $D\alpha (x)$ is zero, but in such a case we cannot employ the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @mathcounterexample.net Am I right ?